# Showing that Fa ⊢ ∃x(x=a∧Fx)

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm trying to using natural deduction calculus to prove the above argument. The problem is I don't know what I should assume in order to obtain Fx, or x=a?

It's not apparent to me what I can assume that would follow with a valid discharge.

Comment: Suppose you showed that $a = a \wedge Fa$; would that show the right hand side? It sure feels that way to me. I think you'd use the "existential quantifier introduction rule" to draw this implication. And then you'd only need to show (i) that $a = a$ and (ii) that $Fa$, probably using the $\wedge I$ deduction rule. But I should add that I know virtually nothing about this subject.

Comment: @JohnHughes I just posted an answer as it finally dawned on me. You are exactly correct. What wasn't obvious to me before was that a=a would become x=a upon application of the existential quantifier. So with that knowledge it's clear you just need to show a=a∧Fa before its application and voila

Comment: Hey... I must have learned something in all that reading I've been doing in the last few months! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\def\fitch#1#2{\begin{array}{|l}#1 \\ \hline #2\end{array}}$

$\fitch{1. \ Fa}{2. \ a=a \quad = \ Intro\\ 
3. Fa \land a=a \quad \land \ Intro \ 1,2\\
4. \exists x \ ( x = a \land Fx) \quad \exists \ Intro \ 3}$

Answer (score 3):

After thinking about it a little it became clear - although only by chance.

My answer thus would be:

1. $Fa$   Ass(Premise)
2. $a=a$  =I
3. $a=a\land Fx$ $∧$I 1,2
4. $∃x(x=a\land Fx)$ $\exists$ I 3

Comment: You actually beat me by 30 seconds! :)